# PHP Mysqli character encoding

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How come that this:

```
$tekst = "ideeën";
$query = "UPDATE `home` SET `tekst`='" . $conn->real_escape_string($tekst) . "' WHERE `section` = 'welkom'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("query fout " . mysqli_error($conn) );
```

Is stored in the database as: ideeÃ«n

Comment: Collation/character set issue.

Comment: your database column data type must be utf-8-bin if you want exact word to save.

Comment: That didn't work. Something else that may help someone come up with the solution: When I edit the text manually in PHPMyAdmin, it does work.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry too much about how it appears in the database.  As long as your treatment of the value going into the database and then drawing back out is the same, how it appears in your SQL client should be irrelevant.

Comment: I'll work with the SQL client side then if solving this seems like an issue, thanks anyways :)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Calling the escaping functions manually is asking for trouble.

Comment: If it's not table or field charset issue then it could be your connection defaulting to latin1 while your actual php file is utf8. To fix you must tell the server that your php client is using utf8 http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: what is your database collation ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the character set of the connection?

```
/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: I had this problem in the past. At one point had to fix it because I needed to share the data with another web app, but that involved also changing the data in the database.